# Trying to get my bot to kick members that spam and have more than 3 violations

Tags: bots, discord, python-3.7

I can get the bot to delete spam messages perfectly, I cannot get it to kick members who's violation count is over 3.

```
if message.author.name in logs:            
       if message.author.name in users is True:
           return
       else:
           delta = message.created_at-logs[message.author.name].lastMessage
           if(delta.seconds < timeout):
               logs[message.author.name].violations += 1
               await message.delete()
               print("Spam Detected!")
               print("In Channel:", message.channel)
               print("Spammer:", message.author.name)
               print("Message: " + message.clean_content)
               print("Time Deleted:", str(datetime.datetime.now()), "\n")
               name = message.author.name
               if name in logs:
                   log = logs[name]
                   if log.violations > 3:
                       await discord.Member.kick(reason=None)
       logs[message.author.name].lastMessage = message.created_at

else:
       logs[message.author.name] = Log(message.created_at)
```

The await discord.Member.kick(reason=None) pulls an error of TypeError: kick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

I've also tried using await discord.Guild.kick(user=user, reason=None) with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `await message.guild.kick(message.author)`.
(Note that gives an error if the message is not sent in a guild)

Basically it fetches the guild that the message was sent in with `message.Guild`, and kicks the person who sent the message (`message.author`).

The reason why `discord.Member.kick(reason=None)` did not work was because `discord.Member` was a type, not an object.

Doing `message.author` should have been the correct way.

(It would also make more sense since its saying "fetch the author of this message", rather than saying "fetch the member of this discord", given the fact that there are a lot of members on discord)

The following reason is the same for `discord.Guild.kick(user=user, reason=None)` not working.

Comment: Yay! Okay so that's working, I'm testing it in a private server with just the bot and myself before sending it to the server it's supposed to go to (over 33k members so i want to make sure everything works correctly) ANYWAYYYY Im getting the Missing permissions error, would that be because im the owner of the server? under the client.event decorator I have has permissions decorator, is this correct? @ has_permissions(administrator=True, manage_messages=True, view_channel=True, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, manage_channel=True, kick_members=True) and if not, what am i missing?

Comment: @BrandonWeeks Your bot obviously needs Kick permission. But if the kicking still fails due to permission error, it would mostly be the fact that your bot is trying to kick someone who has more authority than the bot.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it didn't go rogue and kick people it shouldn't :] Seems like this issue has been resolved, thank you all!